# SharedPreference is not working after install

Tags: android

When I connect my Android Device to a computer and Run App (Run apps unknown sources is enabled and device debugging is enabled) in device it is working fine.

If I share that app with any other Android supported devices, after   installing, unfortunately it stopped.

If I connect that device to computer and run it is working.

Actually we are sharing development app with others for testing purpose.

Comment: which OS is used by device you're debugging on?

Comment: You said its development apk . Then see the error logs . You can use [crashlytic](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) to monitor crashed .

Comment: As ManisNegi stated, it could be OS related issue if you are debugging on a device below Android 6.0 and testing with one above 6.0. It could be a run time permission issue but it's just wild guess. You should use crash logging framework to be sure.

Comment: please show here error log.

Comment: the issue is that after unstall the app completely if we are running again its come from main screen only its not going to login activity and if we are clear the app data its running from start i mean from login activity.

Comment: we are using right now 7.0

Comment: you can enable debug for rekease apk by putting buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
in your  gradle.build file and do the same process by putting some point breakpoint where you suspect. It is really hard to tell without seeing code what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the apk build in debug mode then, the application will not work in other devices by sharing the apk using xender or other sharing applications. I also faced the same issue once.

I recommend you to build the application in release mode.

Or you can share the apk from PC to mobile device using xender web application this will also work http://web.xender.com/